# Why do you need to use while loops as opposed to if statements when working with condition variables?

Tags: operating-system, condition-variable, locks

There is all sorts of documentation online and in books that say that you should always use a while loop as opposed to an if statement when using condition variables, but I have never seen a clear explanation as to why.  I understand spurious wakeups can occur, but if this happens, wouldn't the thread still be checking the condition of the if statement?  What makes a while loop so different?

What is the difference in outcomes between these two snippets of pseudocode?

```
lock(mu)
count--;
unlock(mu)
if(count > 0) {
lock(mu)
wait(cond, mu)
unlock(mu)
}
else{
lock(mu)
signal(cond)
unlock(mu)
}
```

```
lock(mu)
count--;
unlock(mu)
while (count > 0) {
lock(mu)
wait(cond, mu)
unlock(mu)
}

lock(mu)
signal(cond)
unlock(mu)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between using a while loop and an if statement when using condition variables is that the former ensures that the thread will continue to check the condition even after it has been notified. In the case of a spurious wakeup, where the thread is awakened without the condition actually being met, the while loop will cause the thread to go back to sleep and continue waiting until the condition is actually satisfied.

In contrast, the if statement will only check the condition once, before the thread goes to sleep. If a spurious wakeup occurs, the thread will not go back to sleep and will continue execution without checking the condition again. This can lead to incorrect behavior and potential race conditions.

Therefore, using a while loop is recommended when using condition variables to ensure that the thread continues to check the condition until it is actually satisfied. This avoids potential issues with spurious wakeups and ensures that the thread behaves as expected.